# PhpStorm - fluent interface

Tags: php, phpstorm

When using fluent interface within a class and trying to call the functions of this class one by one from another function of this class

f.e.

```
mainFunction()
{
    $this
        ->func1()
        ->func2()
        ->func3()
        ->func4()
        ->func5()
    ;
}
```

PhpStorm is not able to connect the call with the function definition after the 4th function is called so the 5th function definition gets info

> Unused private method func5  Direct usages of the private method are
>   not found.

and the call gets info

> Method 'func5' not found in  Referenced method is not found in
>   subject class.

Is there any configurable limit set for that?

Comment: Show real code sample -- how those functions are defined etc. 5 chained calls is not a problem in general. For optimisation purposes IDE may loose the chain after 20th call .. but 5 should work just fine.

Comment: well that is really not relevant how they are defined, there is nothing special about them, they are all private methods of a class, they all return $this at the very end, they have no other return statements inside, and they are all called one by one like shown in the example, if I change the chain order, always the last one is "broken" so if I move func1 to the end so it is called as the last one then this function will end up being "broken"

Comment: so yeah, probably there is something relevant because a dummy class does not show the same problem, but I don't know what s causing it yet, funny is when i break the chain into two, calling first 4 functions, ending the chain and starting another one with another $this-> call, it works just fine, until 5 calls in a row are called, I will obfuscate the code later and post example

Comment: Could be relevant.  What is `func4()` returning?  FYI, I have fluent interfaces that chain many more than 5 calls.

Comment: as I already wrote this is fluent interface so all functions return $this at the very end, and have no other return statements inside, this must be some PHPStorm thing... please read my previous comments, if I change the chain order and switch func4 and func5, func5 starts "working" and func4 becomes one that is "broken"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ran into a known bug of PhpStorm 6, that officially should have been fixed in version
8.0.4 (139.1803): [WI-17801 Fluent-style chaining type loss with return this/static](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-17801)

You can work-around the problem, if you specify the classname as return type:

```
class FooBar
{
    // ...

    private function func1(): FooBar
    {
        return $this;
    }

    // ...  
}
```

or, for old PHP versions,

```
class FooBar
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @return FooBar
     */
    private function func1()
    {
        return $this;
    }

    // ...  
}
```

Comment: should have been fixed means it was not? I use the latest 2017.1.4, and the fix that you proposed did work when I added the comment to 3rd and  4th function declaration, so it is not enough to add it just to the last one before the broken one

Comment: It should be fixed according to the issue on the tracker that I linked to. Maybe it is a regression, I don't know for sure.  I've never ran into that problem myself, but I could reproduce it (getting the error at call #26). -- You should add the type hint to *all* methods.

Comment: @olechafm This is what I was talking about (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-17375). You said that you are using 2017.**1**.4 .. which is a bit old. I would suggest to try latest stable which is 2017.**3**.x (unless that was a typo).